# How to refresh page?

Tags: asp.net

i am writing an asp.net page with c#  - i have DB and a table on the page which view the DB content
i have function that update a line in the DB - i call it by clicking on a button- the function refresh & update the DB- but not the page- how can i do that???

Comment: can you post some code, expand on how you are connecting page to db?

Comment: i connect by link to sql- simple select sentence

Answer (score 0):

If you have a databound control that's displaying the data, try calling it's `DataBind()` method

```
dataBoundControl.DataBind()
```

else if you are manually constructing the table that displays the data, call the routine that builds the table after you update the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```